# Enter Git branch filters using wildcard characters in TFS2015 CI Build

Tags: git, continuous-integration, tfs-2015

Visual Studio [documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/triggers) advises that we should be able to use wildcard characters to specify the Git branches that we want to trigger builds.

However, when I try and enter a partial branch name with an asterisk, I don't seem to be able to enter that field value as a filter, either using Tab or Enter keys:

[image]

I must be missing something obvious, but **how should we enter (and save) such Git branch filters with wildcards**, please?

P.S. A branch matching the search pattern does exist, but I need to specifically only set a filter (as opposed to select an existing branch name from a drop-down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just type your filter in the field and hit Enter. Then save the build definition.

Don't pay attention to that statement `No branches contain the filter text`. Might not be obvious UI decision, but works just fine.

Comment: I honestly thought I tried this yesterday (as mentioned in my question - tried Tab and Enter), but hey, tried it again today and it works, so thank you!